# Extract names of dataframes passed with dots

Tags: r, ellipsis

One can use `deparse(substitute())` combination to extract the parameter name inside the function like this function

```
names_from_dots <- function(...) {
    deparse(substitute(...))
 }

data(iris)
data(swiss)

names_from_dots(iris)
#[1] "iris"
names_from_dots(swiss)
#[1] "swiss"
```

extracts the name of a data.frame passed in `...` (dots) parameter.

But how can one extract every name of passed multiple data.frames

```
names_from_dots(swiss, iris)
[1] "swiss"
names_from_dots(iris, swiss)
[1] "iris"
```

When this only returns the name of the first object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
names_from_dots <- function(...) sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)

names_from_dots(swiss, iris)
# [1] "swiss" "iris"
```

Answer (score 20):

I wouldn’t use `substitute` here at all, it works badly with `...`<sup>1</sup>. Instead, you can just capture the unevaluated dots using:

```
dots = match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
```

Then you can get the arguments inside the dots:

```
sapply(dots, deparse)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Part of the reason is, I think, that `substitute` does completely different things when called with (a) an argument (which is a “promise” object) or (b) another object. `...` falls somewhere in between these two.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, using the rlang package (based on H. Wickham, Advanced R, [Section 19.3.2](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#capturing-symbols)):

```
names_from_dots <- function(...) as.character(rlang::ensyms(...))
names_from_dots(swiss, iris)
# [1] "swiss" "iris"
```