# Use dot dot dot (...) to indicate columns returned from a self-defined function for a data.table object

Tags: r, function, data.table, ellipsis

I want to use `...` to indicate the variables I want to return from a self-defined function for a `data.table` object. Here is a minimal replicable example:

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(mtcars)

getvar = function(...){
  return(d[,.(xyz = mean(hp), ...), cyl])
}

getvar(mpg, cyl, disp)
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(d, , .(N = .N, ...), cyl) : 
>     object 'cyl' not found

What I wish to get is:

```
d[,.(xyz = mean(hp), mpg, cyl, disp), cyl]

 #    cyl       xyz  mpg cyl  disp
 # 1:   6 122.28571 21.0   6 160.0
 # 2:   6 122.28571 21.0   6 160.0
 # 3:   6 122.28571 21.4   6 258.0
 # 4:   6 122.28571 18.1   6 225.0
 # 5:   6 122.28571 19.2   6 167.6
```

Anyone can share their solutions?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51259346/680068

Comment: What is the use case for this?  And I know this is beside the point, but ```d[, xyz:= mean(hp), cyl]``` would be a simple implementation

Comment: @Cole If the data to be input is a wide data, then it is necessary to return a data.table with limited number of columns.

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution is using `mget` in your function wich returns a list and then combining `xyz` with that with `c`. The columns that you want to add need to be specified as a character vector to make this work:

```
getvar = function(...){
  return(d[, c(xyz = mean(hp), mget(...)), cyl])
}

getvar(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > getvar(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"))
>     cyl       xyz  mpg cyl  disp
>  1:   6 122.28571 21.0   6 160.0
>  2:   6 122.28571 21.0   6 160.0
>  3:   6 122.28571 21.4   6 258.0
>  4:   6 122.28571 18.1   6 225.0
>  5:   6 122.28571 19.2   6 167.6
>  6:   6 122.28571 17.8   6 167.6
>  7:   6 122.28571 19.7   6 145.0
>  8:   4  82.63636 22.8   4 108.0
>  9:   4  82.63636 24.4   4 146.7
> 10:   4  82.63636 22.8   4 140.8
> ....
> ```

---

Or as an alternative a slight variation of [@Rhonak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58706965/2204410) (thx to @zx8754):

```
getvar = function(...){
  mc <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  x <- as.character(mc$...)
  d[, c(xyz = mean(hp), mget(x)), cyl]
}

getvar(mpg, cyl, disp)
```

Comment: Ah, but you are using quotes `""`.

Answer (score 3):

To get this to work without quoting the column names, you'd have to use some non-standard evaluation tactics:

```
getvar = function(...){
  vars <- substitute(list(xyz = mean(hp), ...))
  return(d[, eval(vars), cyl])
}

getvar(mpg, cyl, disp)
```

```
    cyl       xyz  mpg cyl  disp
 1:   6 122.28571 21.0   6 160.0
 2:   6 122.28571 21.0   6 160.0
 3:   6 122.28571 21.4   6 258.0
 4:   6 122.28571 18.1   6 225.0
 5:   6 122.28571 19.2   6 167.6
...etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Building up on answer by @Konrad Rudolph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317968/3962914), we can write the function

```
getvar = function(...){
   dots = match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
   cols = sapply(dots, deparse)
   d[, c(xyz = mean(hp), mget(cols)), cyl]
   #thanks to @Jaap for simplified version
}

getvar(mpg, cyl, disp)
#    cyl    xyz  mpg cyl  disp
# 1:   6 122.29 21.0   6 160.0
# 2:   6 122.29 21.0   6 160.0
# 3:   6 122.29 21.4   6 258.0
# 4:   6 122.29 18.1   6 225.0
# 5:   6 122.29 19.2   6 167.6
# 6:   6 122.29 17.8   6 167.6
#....
```

Comment: `d[, c(xyz = mean(hp), mget(cols)), cyl]` instead of `d[, xyz := mean(hp), cyl][,mget(c("xyz", cols))]`?